# Thread for posts needing development work

Tags: discussion, chat

I understand that GIS.SE is not about finding or promoting GIS consultancy, but occassionally you get a question from a user who's problem clearly exceeds their knowledge level in GIS or who is specifically looking for a function which does not exist in the package they are using.

Why not have a thread where such quesitons can be moved which does allow consultants to promote their services? It would certainly act as an incentive for consultants to build up their reputation points on the main site?

Comment: Use chat for that.

Answer (score 6):

Basically because, this is a Q& A site. If you have a question related to GIS, this is the place for it. A job or consultancy as such does not fit within the parameters of the site, as defined in the [FAQ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq)

There are several discussion fourms dedicated to GIS and I am glad, that here the community has maintained the site according to the vision it was meant for.

Having said that, there are still avenues at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/, or you could even post it in the chat.

There is no need to post it as a Question or answer, since it will help no one else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Given that SE has a "related jobs" panel on the main site, I would expect that a job posted to careers.stackoverflow.com could somehow be made to appear there.  A lot of the jobs I see in that panel are not very "related" ... providing members the ability to post jobs to careers.stackoverflow.com and tag so they appear at gis.se would make sense as an enhance request if this has not already been implemented.